# If exist a measurable function  and a continuous function  so that ・ is non-measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Give an example of a measurable function  and a continuous function  so that ・ is non-measurable.

Comment: Look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235718/composition-of-measurable-function-and-continuous-function?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: $f\cdot g$ or $f\circ g$?

Comment: The answer depends on what you mean by measurable. You have not even specified the domain and range so there is no definite answer to this question.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy different than this one $g:(X,\mathcal B(X))\to(Y,\tau_Y)$ for $g$ for sure and $f:X\to Y$ arbitrary I think